# Sql problem with group by and intersection

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this log table in MySQL with columns ActionName and SourceName.

The same actions can be registered multiple times from different sources.

So an example table might look like

```
ActionName    SourceName
----------------------------
Add           S01
Add           S02
Add           S02
Edit          S01
Edit          S01
Delete        S01
Delete        S02
```

Now I would like to query this table and find the actions which have been performed by both S01 and S02. So the results would be:

```
 ActioName
--------------
Add
Delete
```

How would I solve this with SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A specific answer...

```
SELECT
  ActionName
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  SourceName in ('S01', 'S02')
GROUP BY
  ActionName
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT SourceName) = 2
```

Possibly faster for your specific question...

```
SELECT
  a.SourceName
FROM
  yourTable  AS a
INNER JOIN
  yourTable  AS b
    ON a.ActionName = b.ActionName
WHERE
      a.SourceName = 'S01'
  AND b.SourceName = 'S02'
```

A general answer...

```
SELECT
  ActionName
FROM
  yourTable
INNER JOIN
  tableWithSourceNames
    ON yourTable.SourceName = tableWithSourceNames.SourceName
GROUP BY
  ActionName
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT yourTable.SourceName) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SourceName) FROM tableWithSourceNames)
```

It turns out that this scales very badly though (as your table increases in size, performance plummets).  You *can* make an optimisation though...

By holding a bit of meta-data about how selective each SourceName is...

```
CREATE TABLE sourceNameMetaData (
  sourceName  VARCHAR(64),
  occurances  INT
)
```

I'd recommend keeping this talbe up to date with a trigger or something.  You can then filter your ActionTable by the entry that is most restrictive, and then do the rest of the logic as normal.

```
SELECT
  yourTable.ActionName
FROM
(
  SELECT
    ActionName
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      sourceName
    FROM
      sourceNameMetaData
    INNER JOIN
      tableWithSourceNames
        ON tableWithSourceNames.SourceName = sourceNameMetaData.SourceName
    ORDER BY
      occurances ASC
    LIMIT
      1
  )
    AS filter    
  INNER JOIN
    yourTable
      ON yourTable.SourceName = filter.SourceName
  GROUP BY
    ActionName
)
  AS filter
INNER JOIN
  yourTable
    ON yourTable.ActionName = filteredData.ActionName
INNER JOIN
  tableWithSourceNames
    ON yourTable.SourceName = tableWithSourceNames.SourceName
GROUP BY
  yourTable.ActionName
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT yourTable.SourceName) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SourceName) FROM tableWithSourceNames)
```

Notes:

- This optimisation isn't needed for small tables
- This optimisation assumes you have indexes on BOTH (sourceName, ActionName) AND (actionName, sourceName)
- It's a brilliant example I use to show that more code CAN be faster

Comment: Calling your own code brilliant is not an invitation to upvotes

Comment: Joking aside, don't forget to add an index to the temp-table.

Comment: The code itself isn't the brilliance.  The fact that the fastest code is the code which is Triple the size is the fact that makes me think it's a brilliant example.  Also, the temp table is going to be scanned in it's entirety regardless, so unless the contents are huge indexing it will have only a marginal advantage.  STILL do index it, even if it's just a clustered primary key, just don't expect that particular index ot have amazing implications :)

Comment: @Dems: `HAVING COUNT(*)=2` would not always show correct results, as in the OP's example. For `Add`, it would be COUNT(*)=3, and `Add` not shown.

Comment: OOPS!  need DISTINCT SourceName instead!

Comment: Thanks! It's really a small table for now. I'll be back in a few months for the optimzation =)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ActionName 
FROM LogTable 
WHERE SourceName IN ('S01', 'S02')
GROUP BY ActionName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SourceName) = 2
```

or:

```
SELECT ActionName 
FROM 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT ActionName
      FROM LogTable
    ) AS dn 
WHERE 
    EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM LogTable AS a
        WHERE a.ActionName = dn.ActionName
          AND a.SourceName = 'S01'
      )
  AND
    EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM LogTable AS b
        WHERE b.ActionName = dn.ActionName
          AND b.SourceName = 'S02'
      )
```

Comment: +1 : If you KNOW that you're only searching for two SourceName's, variations of the second example are usually the fastest solution.

Comment: thnx. And yes, I think second way is usually faster. But dealing with variable number of SourceNames, one has to write dynamic code .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not getting your problem but you wouldn't need to do a group by or much of anything if all you want in the result is what you showed.

```
select distinct ActionName from YourTable 
where SourceName in ('S01', 'S02')
```

Comment: Ah, nevermind.  I see it now.  They both have to have performed it.  One second.